# Understanding the legitimacy of power series manipulations.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Why can operations on the function $f(x)$ correspond to exact operations on the *series representation* of $f(x)$? Dividing an **infinite** series by a variable sounds fishy to me.

*I understand the uniqueness of representations. I understand technique is valid, I want to know the conceptual validity or algebraic evidence of why this is the case.*

This question may very well be trivial in which case downvote away and give me the baptism of fire.

---

**Example**

For function $$f(z)=\frac{\log z}{z-1}$$

Starting from the series expansion on $|z-1|<1$; $$\log z=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(z-1)^n}{n}$$

diving both sides by $z-1$ yields the representation for $f(z)$ as $$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(z-1)^n}{n+1}$$

---

Why is this dividing operation valid? I think there may be many ways to explain and I would love to hear a diverse plethora of explanations, thanks for your time!

Comment: It's like you're dividing the series by a constant. Consider it a number series, not a series of functions. You can do this by assuming that $z$ is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, the expression for $f(z)$ isn't defined for $z = 1$. You could choose to extend it by continuity so that $f(1) = 1$, or not. Regardless, I'm going to assume $z \ne 1$ below.

You don't seem to have any problem with the reindexing or performing the term-by-term division by $z - 1$. The only problem is why

$$\log z=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(z-1)^n}{n}$$
implies
$$\frac{1}{z-1}\log z=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z-1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(z-1)^n}{n}.$$

The answer is that if $\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} b_n$ is any convergent series with sum $B$, and $a$ is a complex number, then the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} ab_n$ is convergent with sum $aB$.

In our example, of course, $a = \frac{1}{z-1}$.